# PassportJS NodeJS Display Error Messages on page

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js, locomotivejs

I am using Locomotivejs and passportJS for auth on a project, and I found some code online to handle register:

```
   AccountController.create = function() {
  var account = new Account();
  console.log("test");
  account.email = this.param('email');
  account.password = this.param('password');
  account.name.first = this.param('first');
  account.name.last = this.param('name.last');

  var self = this;
  account.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);

      return self.redirect(self.urlFor({ action: 'new' }));
    }
    return self.redirect(self.urlFor({ action: 'login' }));
  });
};
```

However I cannot figure out how to display error messages on the page such as "Username already exists" or "passwords do not match" etc. I can only get them to console.log(). Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

[connect-flash](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash) is pretty useful for such situations:

```
// in your app's config:
var flash = require('connect-flash');
...
app.use(flash());
...

// in your #create controller:
if (err) {
  req.flash('error', 'YOUR ERROR MESSAGE HERE');
  return self.redirect(self.urlFor({ action: 'new' }));
}

// in your #new controller:
res.render('TEMPLATE', { errors: req.flash('error') });
```

And in your templates, check if `errors` exists (it's an array) and render the messages.